# When I insert Japanese words like お爺さん into mdb by PHP , it's always not correct in mdb

Tags: php, ms-access

I want to insert お爺さん into my mdb(Microsoft Access Database)  ,but it always doesn't work!
I tried **iconv** to encode UTF-8,and **utf8_encode** to encode UTF-8.Above are all not working!
Here is my code.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=Utf-8"/></head>
<?php
    include("config.php");      
    // query database                       
    $dbname = $baseDir."/slave/QBSH20131225.mdb";
    $connStr = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=".$dbname."; Uid=; Pwd=;");                  
    $test = "お爺さん";
    echo "Insert ".$test."<p>";
    echo mb_detect_encoding($test);// echo UTF-8
    echo $test;//echo お爺さん      
    $sql = "INSERT INTO song ";
    $sql .= " (id,singer,songName)";
    $sql .= " VALUES ('16498','pahome','".$test."')";
    $connStr->query($sql);              
    $sql = 'SELECT id, singer ,songName FROM song where id =16498 ';
    $result = $connStr->query($sql);$row = $result->fetch();
    print_r($row);// print ?�爺?��?              
    echo "<p> ADODB.connection is finished <p>";
    $connStr->Close();      
    ?>
 </html>
```

When I use SELECT to get it,it shows ?�爺?��? in Web page 
And when I check it in mdb ,it shows ???

**PS:when I insert English ,the result is all correct.So I am sure no error in grammar.**

Did anyone have relative experience like this??Please teach me !
It's a hard trouble for me 
Thank u very much!

Comment: Does this happen with all Japanese words/characters?  Or just お爺さん?

Comment: Provide a table ddl here

Comment: @Manmaru   all Japanese words/charaters

Comment: @Basilevs where to get table ddl ??

Comment: @Basilevs what is the encoding or collation used for the table `song` - is it set to UTF-8?

Comment: @Manmaru  that's the problem,I use Traditional Chinese Microsoft Access.It has a choice "accept unicode encoding ?" and I choose yes.But it can't accept UTF-8 encoding like what I say